# Implementing a function that sums integers contained in a string in Python

Tags: python

So I've recently picked up John Guttag's Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python,the revised and expanded edition, after having worked through most of LPTHW. I am using the book in conjunction with MIT OCW 006. Now, I was trying to complete one of the Finger Exercises listed in the book, specifically the one of page 85, chapter 7, where the author asks you to implement a function using a try-except block:

```
def sumDigits(s):
"""Assumes s is a string
   Returns the sum of the decimal digits in s
   For example, if is is'a2b3c' it returns 5"""
```

This is my code:

```
def sumDigits(s):
  try:  
    total = 0
    list1 = [s]
    new_list = [x for x in list1 if x.isdigit()]
    for e in new_list:
      total += new_list[e]
    return total
  except TypeError:
    print "What you entered is not a string."
```

When I run this program in the IDLE using a test input, the total is always computed to be zero, indicating that none of the elements of new_list are being passed to the accumulator. Could someone suggest why that is? Thanks.

Comment: What is  the test input?

Comment: You should be iterating over `s` not `[s]`?

Comment: Oh, I used a few different inputs actually, 'agfj56' and 'ghjg39' being a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually several errors with your code. 
Let's break them down in detail

The main problem is located in these lines:

```
list1 = [s]
new_list = [x for x in list1 if x.isdigit()]
```

You should loop directly over the string first

```
new_list = [x for x in s if x.isdigit()] #s is the input string
```

When you create a new list as you did, the variable `x` in `x for x in list1` will take place as elements of the list. So, in your case, the list will have only one element, which happen to be whole string (because you defined the list as `[s]`. As the whole string is not a digit, `new_list` will be an empty list. 
That is why you are getting 0 as a return.

However, if you loop through the string directly, `x` will take place as each letter in the string, and then it will be possible to check whether `x` is digit or not.

It is also important to highlight that `new_list[e]` will raise `IndexError`. You should correct that for `e` only. The sintax of `for e in new_list` makes the local variable `e` assume **each** value inside the list, so you do not have to get the value via indexes: you can use `e` directly. 
Finally, in order to sum the values in your new_list, the values should be integers (`int`) and not string (`str`), so you have to cast the values to `int` before summing (or, you can cast each element to `int` during the list comprehension, by using `int(x) for x in s if x.isdigit()` instead of `x for x in s if x.isdigit()`). Also, in order to check if the input is a string or not, you better use `isinstance(s, basestring)` if you're in python2, or `isinstance(s, str)` if you're using python3.

So the whole code would look like this :

```
def sumDigits(s):
  if isinstance(s, basestring):  
    total = 0
    new_list = [x for x in s if x.isdigit()]
    for e in new_list:
      total += int(e)
    return total
  else:
    print "What you entered is not a string."
```

Comment: You never hit your error block.  sumDigits(['x', 'y', 'z'])
Out[87]: 0

Comment: Yeah, that what part os his code. `isinstance` would fit better for checking if its a string or not

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the errors have been pointed out already by Rafael but it is still important to note that the more pythonic way to approach this would be:

```
return sum([int(x) for x in s if x.isdigit()])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through the same book and the MITx: 6.00.1x course on edX; here's my solution:

```
def sumDigits(s):
    '''
    Assumes s is a string
    Returns the sum of the decimal digits in s
    For example, if s is 'a2b3c' it returns 5
    '''
    result = 0
    try:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i].isdigit():
                result += int(s[i])
        return result
    except:
        print('Your input is not a string.')
```

Since we are to assume that s is a string, the except block should handle those cases where s is not a string. So simple, but it was not obvious to me at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **reduce** method

`reduce( (lambda x, y: x + y), [int(x) for x in new if x.isdigit()] )`

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through the same book too. I think we should use the try-except block on determining whether characters of string convertible to an integer. So here is my solution.

```
def sumDigits(s):
"""Assumes s is a string
Returns the sum of the decimal digits in s
For example, if s is 'a2b3c' it returns 5"""
sum = 0
for i in s:
    try:
        sum += int(i)
    except ValueError:
        None
return sum
```